# How can I deprecate a function in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, annotations, deprecated

Java-docs allows a functionality which lets you show when a function is deprecated. You can put an annotation *@Deprecated* before the function and it will appear crossed in the code. This is a good mechanism to tell to the rest of the developers that they should avoid to use this function, and is very convenient for refactoring. Is any similar functionality for ColdFusion? Has anyone any workaround for these scenarios?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there isn't a built in facility to do this, and no real mechanism I can think of you could co-opt to effect the same thing.

It'd be ugly, but all I can think is that you stick a logging line in any deprecated function to log to the application log that a deprecated function has been called. You could probably use some sort of AOP framework / mechanism to allow you to only do this in one place, with the deprecation logger logging for metadata on the deprecated function before it calls it..?

Answer (score 0):

We explicitly throw an error in any deprecated function to let the developers know right away to not use it. Our QA testing will catch and report these errors in lower environments as part of our SDLC.

On top of that, we have our Jenkins server run a series of regex based rules in order to find any new instances of native CF functions which we have deprecated from our code base.

Comment: A *deprecated* function should still function as per normal. So throwing an error is not appropriate in this situation.

Comment: OP says that the Java property "is a good mechanism to tell to the rest of the developers that they should avoid to use this function, and is very convenient for refactoring." For us, we have so many teams working on so many branches of code, that we have to force the error to ensure that the deprecated functions aren't just avoided, they never make it past the integration level.

Comment: But then they're not "deprecated", they're simply broken. When something is DEPRECATED it's supposed to still work as per usual. The act odd deprecation is a documentation change, not a functionality change.